# requests-oauthlib custom params

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth, python-requests

I was wondering if there is a way to add custom values into an oauth request in requests-outhlib. Here is the code that I have to get my token however I want to add two more parameters to it.

```
def login_token(self):
    if self.signature_method == 'RSA-SHA1':
        prepare = OAuth1(self.consumer_key, client_secret=self.consumer_secret, callback_uri=self.call_backuri,
                         signature_method='RSA-SHA1',
                         rsa_key=open(self.rsa_location).read(), signature_type='query', verifier=None,)
    else:
        prepare = OAuth1(self.consumer_key, client_secret=self.consumer_secret, callback_uri=self.call_backuri,
                         signature_method='HMAC-SHA1', signature_type='query')
    request = json.loads(requests.post(self.base_url + 'login_token/', auth=prepare).text)
    self.request_token = request['token']['oauth_token']
    return str(self.request_token)
```

Any ideas? I have looked around but I couldn't find much

Comment: Where would those two parameters go? As extra headers on the request?

Comment: I would prefer them to go in the url as a query as right now headers from python are not playing well with the server. The server I am making requests to has a lot of internal politics to so having things changed on it won't happen. So far I have only been able to get things to work by passing in the url

Comment: Then just add those to the POST with `params={'param1': value1, 'param2': value2}` and they'll be used as query parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add parameters to the URL, then do so with the `params` parameter:

```
extra_params = {'param1': value1, 'param2': value2}
request = requests.post(self.base_url + 'login_token/',
                        params=extra_params,
                        auth=prepare).json()
```

Note that `requests` supports loading JSON natively, using the [`response.json()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content). This method uses JSON-RFC-specific heuristics to determine the right character set (while `.text` could get this wrong).

Comment: Works and I have switched to using the native way. I didn't think using params= would work but thank you for helping :)